# BigQuery Pivot leaving out rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I'm querying a BigQuery table with a pivot function and noticed that in the pivot result some rows are missing compared to the original table. It is a very basic query to sum up eventcounts for different eventnames.

The pivot query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
      WHERE date = "2023-05-15") 
PIVOT (SUM(eventcount) AS convs 
       FOR eventname IN ("page_view",
                         "select_item",
                         "view_item",
                         "Store_List_event"))
ORDER BY date,
         useragebracket,
         usergender
```

Compared to the simple `SELECT *` the pivot query is missing some rows for a day. I am able to locate the missing rows but there is no consistent pattern as to why these rows are not being displayed correctly besides the values for some columns are very similar to other rows.

Here's an example sourcetable:

| date | eventname | useragebracket | usergender | eventcount | screenpageviews | sessions | totalusers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-15 | page_view | x-y | xyz | 1348 | 1348 | 194 | 175 |
| 2023-05-15 | view_item | x-y | xyz | 34 | 0 | 15 | 15 |
| 2023-05-15 | select_item | x-y | xyz | 38 | 0 | 15 | 15 |
| 2023-05-15 | Store_List_event | x-y | xyz | 47 | 0 | 15 | 15 |

The query gives me the following result:

| date | useragebracket | usergender | screenpageviews | sessions | totalusers | convs_page_view | convs_select_item | convs_view_item | convs_Store_List_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-15 | x-y | xyz | 1348 | 194 | 175 | 1348 | null | null | null |
| 2023-05-15 | x-y | xyz | 0 | 15 | 15 | null | 38 | 34 | 47 |

My understanding is, as there is no `group by` statement in the surrounding select query, that each row for every seperate eventname should be returned with always exactly one pivoted column being filled. This seems to work except for *some* eventnames but those eventnames are different names for every day. The only similarity seems to be the number of sessions/users for those rows.

Following this idea, I would expect the following output:

| date | useragebracket | usergender | screenpageviews | sessions | totalusers | convs_page_view | convs_select_item | convs_view_item | convs_Store_List_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-15 | x-y | xyz | 1348 | 194 | 175 | 1348 | null | null | null |
| 2023-05-15 | x-y | xyz | 0 | 15 | 15 | null | 38 | null | null |
| 2023-05-15 | x-y | xyz | 0 | 15 | 15 | null | null | 34 | null |
| 2023-05-15 | x-y | xyz | 0 | 15 | 15 | null | null | null | 47 |

Can someone explain this behavior and tell me how to avoid it?

Comment: Hence, what's the expected output you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i edited the question for a more visual representation of the expected result.

Comment: What's the purpose of having 4 records with null values, if you can have one record only that contains all your information?

Comment: The purpose is, that the missing rows have values for sessions and totalusers as well. These values are in the flat table but are being ignored in the pivoted one so, in this case, i'm missing 30 in each column in the overall sum.

Comment: Try the answer in the section below then, maybe can be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe have an explanation for the observed behavior of the pivot query or am i expecting the wrong ouput from it? Just trying to understand the situation in order to use pivot effectively and don't query incorrectly without me knowing.

Comment: I've added what's the conversion of your query into an explicit form in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with pivot, it's better to use the explicit version, as it's clearer what's going on. The translation of your current query, in explicit form, is the following:

```
SELECT date,
       useragebracket,
       usergender,
       screenpageviews,
       sessions,
       totalusers,
       MAX(CASE WHEN eventname = 'page_view'        THEN eventcount) END AS convs_page_view,
       MAX(CASE WHEN eventname = 'view_item'        THEN eventcount) END AS convs_view_item,
       MAX(CASE WHEN eventname = 'select_item'      THEN eventcount) END AS convs_select_item,
       MAX(CASE WHEN eventname = 'Store_List_event' THEN eventcount) END AS convs_Store_List_event
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
      WHERE date = "2023-05-15") tab
GROUP BY date,
         useragebracket,
         usergender,
         screenpageviews,
         sessions,
         totalusers
ORDER BY date,
         useragebracket,
         usergender
```

In this case, it looks like you don't need a pivot at all, but only `CASE` expressions to select your data in different fields.

```
SELECT date,
       useragebracket,
       usergender,
       screenpageviews,
       sessions,
       totalusers,
       CASE WHEN eventname = 'page_view'        THEN eventcount END AS convs_page_view,
       CASE WHEN eventname = 'view_item'        THEN eventcount END AS convs_view_item,
       CASE WHEN eventname = 'select_item'      THEN eventcount END AS convs_select_item,
       CASE WHEN eventname = 'Store_List_event' THEN eventcount END AS convs_Store_List_event
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
WHERE date = "2023-05-15"
ORDER BY date,
         useragebracket,
         usergender
```

Comment: With explicit version you mean explicitly aliasing the pivot columns of the IN statement, right?
I'll try the statement as soon as i can.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the explicit version really does make it clear! I just used the function the wrong way. I was looking for something to sum up the other metrics as well (sessions, screenpageviews, totalusers) and not to group by them which PIVOT seems not to be designed to do.